# Recvfrom() is not receiving all the data sent to the system

Tags: c, sockets

I have a code looks like this where I'm scanning all the ports of VM(10.0.0.1 ) from my system (10.0.0.2) using raw_socket.

```
int main(){
int raw_sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
ip_header->ihl = 5;
ip_header->version = 4;
ip_header->tos = 0;
ip_header->tot_len =  sizeof (struct tcphdr) + sizeof (struct ip);
ip_header->id = htons (54321);
ip_header->frag_off = htons(16384);
ip_header->ttl = 64;
ip_header->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
ip_header->check = 0;
ip_header->saddr = inet_addr (source_ip);   
ip_header->daddr = destination_ip.s_addr;
...
//Same way I fill tcp header
tcp_header->source = htons (source_port);
tcp_header->dest = htons (80);
tcp_header->seq = htonl(1105024978);
tcp_header->ack_seq = 0;
tcp_header->doff = sizeof(struct tcphdr) / 4;       //Size of tcp header
tcp_header->fin=0;
tcp_header->syn=1;//Sending syn packet to the target
tcp_header->rst=0;
tcp_header->psh=0;
tcp_header->ack=0;
tcp_header->urg=0;
tcp_header->window = htons ( 14600);    // maximum allowed window size
tcp_header->check = 0;
tcp_header->urg_ptr = 0;
...
//Set IP_HDRINCL: Indicate kernel of header
...

//Create a thread to handle recv
int a = pthread_create(&thID, NULL, handle_receive, NULL);
...
destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
destination.sin_addr.s_addr = destination_ip.s_addr;
...
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
     sendto (raw_sock, packet ,...);

...
sleep(10);
return 0;//closes all program without waiting for threads to join
}

void* handle_receive(void *){
   while(1){
      data_size = recvfrom(raw_sock_global , buffer , 65536*128 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
   }
}
```

Here after sending all the packets I'm giving 10 seconds delay so that system receives all the replies.

I'm scanning 1-100 ports of VM(10.0.0.1) using my program(which is at IP 10.0.0.2). I don't have any filtered ports on that particular VM. So it replies back with RST+ACK to all the 100 sendto requests (Which I verified from tshark dump).

Even when I run tshark on my program system(10.0.0.2), I can see all the replies coming back. But recvfrom sometimes won't be able to detect all the replies(which I checked keeping a counter just below the recvfrom statement).

I have increased the buffer size of the recvfrom, thinking it could be the problem but it did not help. Also increasing the sleep time did not help either.

Comment: Does the name `raw_socket` in fact designate the descriptor of a socket with family `AF_INET` and type `SOCK_RAW`?  If so, then how are you scanning ports, since ports are not an IP-layer feature?

Comment: Overall, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, as the chances are reasonably good that the issue is not in the code fragments you've presented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have added some more details. Please check.

Comment: I was debugging and found that it does not recv the initial few replies sent sometimes (in tshark it shows reply back to sending port from port 1,2,3 and so on. But it skips first few replies sometimes and gets reply from say port 30,31,32...). @JohnBollinger

Comment: Also there is no problem in receiving if I scan any domain(www.domewebsite.com). Only when I give VM IP i get this problem. I have also tested by giving my college server ip :P and it works. @JohnBollinger